# How can I load JSON data in a tableview faster?

Tags: json, swift

I'm trying to populate a tableViewController with a list of Hacker News articles. The url request returns an array of Integers, which are each posts's ID.

I'm then fetching the current item by its id in a separate request.

Is there a more efficient way to do this? Right now, this tableview takes 10 seconds to load.

```
let baseUrl = URL(string: "https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/")

// This method fetches all the top stories
func fetchStories() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
            let newsUrl = "\(self.baseUrl!)topstories.json"
            Alamofire.request(newsUrl).responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response) in
                if let json = response.result.value as? NSArray {
                    for item in json {
                        let itemId = "\(item)"
                        dispatchGroup.enter()
                        Story.fetchStory(id: itemId, completion: { (story) in
                            self.stories.append(story)
                            dispatchGroup.leave()
                        })
                    }
                }
                dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main, execute: {
                    self.storiesUpdated?()
                })
            })
        }
    }


// This method fetches each story by its id

class func fetchStory(id: String, completion: @escaping (Story) -> Swift.Void) {
    let url = URL(string: "https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/\(id).json?print=pretty")
    Alamofire.request(url!).responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response) in
        if let json = response.result.value as? [String:Any] {
            let newStory = Story(dictionary: json)
            completion(newStory)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Are you waiting for all the stories before updating the list? Have you tried updating in between requests?

Comment: Also, you don't need pretty JSON to parse it

Comment: Why are you trying to fetch data by using the main queue? I would use the background one instead. Also if you have views hierarchy like master and detail, and you need to show details with Story objects, why don't you try to get the  top stories in master with some additional info and fetch stories details only for the detail controller? In other words, don't fetch data if you are not going to use them in current view, it will save time and memory. Also it's good practice to add a pagination for large data